Autoloader Not Picking Up .text Files in Streaming Mode
I am using Databricks Autoloader to process files in streaming (micro-batch) mode. The source files are in .text format. While the checkpoints are created and the stream does not fail, the Delta table is not created, and it seems like the files are not being picked up at all.

(spark.readStream
    .format("cloudFiles")
    .option("cloudFiles.format", "text")
    .option("encoding", "UTF-16")
    .load(source_path)
    .withColumn("sourcefile", F.col("_metadata.file_path")) 
    # .withColumn("load_timestamp", F.to_timestamp(F.regexp_extract(F.col("sourcefile"), "([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})", 1), 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss'))           
    .writeStream
    .option("checkpointLocation", sink_path + '/checkpoints')
    # .option("path", sink_path + '/delta')
    .trigger(availableNow=True)  # Process the file once and stop, new config
    .foreachBatch(lambda batch_df, batch_id: foreach_batch(batch_df, batch_id, sink_path, source_path, table_name, version, meta_data_path))
    .queryName(f"AIDA_{BU}_staging")
    .start()
    .awaitTermination()
)


I’ve checked the following:
The checkpoint directory is being created.
The stream runs without any errors.
Despite this, the Delta table isn’t being created, and it seems like the .text files aren’t being processed.
Could there be an issue with my configuration, or am I missing some necessary options for Autoloader?

Do you see any ERROR while reading file from source?

The stream runs without any errors, but there’s no result, there is no delta table being created. If I just readStream and do a display(df), I just see the dataframe with my headers (I pass a schema myself).
I also tried reading the files using the CSV format, same issue.

I have tried the below approach:
from pyspark.sql.functions import decode
df = (spark.readStream
      .format("cloudFiles")
      .option("cloudFiles.format", "binaryFile")
      .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", schema_loc)
      .load(source_data_loc))
decoded_df = df.withColumn("File_Data", decode(col("content"), "UTF-8"))
(decoded_df.writeStream
    .format("delta")
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_loc)
    .outputMode("append")
    .start(target_data_loc))
display(decoded_df)

In the above code reading the stream using the binary format.
Decoding the content using the UTF-8
Writing the data to a Delta table
Results:



Shoaib Maroof can you check if the above solution helped you?

@Shoaib Maroof Can you please check if the solution helped you?

@Shoaib Maroof Can you please check if the solution helped you?
